# Obtain a list of most "heavy" images from a site

Tags: google-chrome, optimization, google-chrome-devtools, profiling, image-optimization

In the Chrome DevTools, is there a way to obtain a list of most heavy loaded pictures from a site? 
we are working of the site optimisation, so try to figure out the "bag" pictures.

Like the bellow one, but to be able to export it in form of a text list of links something like this....
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that there is an option when you right-click the list in the network tab [image]

HAR is a kind of the `JSON` file.
Now there [are tools](https://www.yamamoto.com.ar/blog/?p=201) permitting to convert an JSON (HAR) file to `CSV` file, that could be open in, say, Excel for further analysis.